# Twitter Web Intents: Retweet link does not appear

Tags: html, web, twitter

I want to use Twitter Web Intents to show modal windows for actions "Like" and "Retweet". My code (acording to https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/web-intents/overview)

```
<html>
    <header>
        <title>Twitter</title> 
    </header>
    <body>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id=463440424141459456">Retweet</a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/like?tweet_id=463440424141459456">Like</a>

        <script type="text/javascript" async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But all I see it is "Like" link. "Retweet" link does not appear.

[Chrome DevTools Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1vlp.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my answer: the reason is "AdGuard" exteinsion for browser. It adds "injected stylesheet". One of rule:

```
a[href^="https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id"]{
    display: none !important;
}
```

[Chrome DevTools Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVFW5.png)

Sorry, this is my inattention.